# Ajax toolkit file upload is not called

Tags: c#, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have two ajaxtoolkit file ulopads on the same page like

```
 <ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload
        id="AjaxFileUpload1"
        AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg,gif,png"
        OnUploadComplete="ajaxUpload2_OnUploadComplete"
        runat="server"  />
         <ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload
        id="ajaxUpload1"
        AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg,gif,png"
        OnUploadComplete="ajaxUpload1_OnUploadComplete"
        runat="server"  />
```

and code behind

```
protected void ajaxUpload2_OnUploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {

        string filePath = "~/Images/" + e.FileName;
        filePath = filePath.Split('\\').Last();
        Session["img2"] = filePath.ToString();
        AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(MapPath(filePath));

    }

    protected void ajaxUpload1_OnUploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {

        string filePath = "~/Images/" + e.FileName;
        filePath = filePath.Split('\\').Last();
        Session["img1"] = filePath.ToString();
        ajaxUpload1.SaveAs(MapPath(filePath));

    }
```

The question is whenever I use upload AjaxFileUpload1 it works on and calls void ajaxUpload2_OnUploadComplete method but if I use ajaxUpload1 the method ajaxUpload2_OnUploadComplete  is called again but the method ajaxUpload1 is not called

Why??

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We got the same problem yesterday and we found out that **you cannot have** more than one **instance of AjaxFileUpload** on the same page.

If you look at the source code, you'll see that this **control use** a **constant GUID** to identify its events. Since the **GUID is a constant**, all **instances of AjaxFileUpload** use the **same GUID.**..

**Result :**

> the first instance swallow all the events...

Here is the GUID in action :

```
private const string ContextKey = "{DA8BEDC8-B952-4d5d-8CC2-59FE922E2923}";

(...)

if (this.Page.Request.QueryString["contextkey"] == ContextKey && this.Page.Request.Files.Count > 0)
```

Comment: @SRo I have same problem.. Can you suggest me to how can i fix this

Comment: @Vignesh Kumar : I didn't find a solution at that time. I just replaced the Ajax Toolkit Upload control with a simple ASP.NET file upload control (I my memory is correct :) Cheers.

Comment: @VigneshKumar: The accepted answer is false; you can have more than one instance of AjaxFileUpload on a page.  See my answer below, its actually really easy to do

Answer (score 2):

We customized the September 2012 toolkit as follows - hope this is a temporary workaround and that this is fixed in a future release:

OLD

```
private const string ContextKey = "{DA8BEDC8-B952-4d5d-8CC2-59FE922E2923}";
```

NEW

```
private string ContextKey = "";
```

OLD

```
public AjaxFileUpload()
            : base(true, HtmlTextWriterTag.Div)
        {
        }
```

NEW

```
public AjaxFileUpload()
            : base(true, HtmlTextWriterTag.Div)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Items["lastAjaxFileUploadContextKey"] == null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Items["lastAjaxFileUploadContextKey"] = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Items["lastAjaxFileUploadContextKey"] = (int)HttpContext.Current.Items["lastAjaxFileUploadContextKey"] + 1;
            }

            ContextKey = HttpContext.Current.Items["lastAjaxFileUploadContextKey"].ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

There actually is a way to use multiple AjaxFileUpload controls on a single page, with each control firing its own event.  The solution is very simple; it involves overriding one of Microsoft's client-side functions for the AjaxFileUpload control to inject information on the control that actually caused the upload complete event, then using a single event handler for all of the AjaxFileUpload controls as a "switchboard", which will subsequently fire the correct event handler for the control which created the event server-side.

Here's how to do it:

Add this script block somewhere after the head element of your page.  If you're using master pages, put this in a placeholder for HTML content:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Sys.Extended.UI.AjaxFileUpload.Control.prototype.doneAndUploadNextFile = function (c) {
        var a = new XMLHttpRequest, b = this;
        a.open("POST", "?contextKey=" + this._contextKey + "&done=1&guid=" + c._id + "&uplCtrlID=" + b.get_id(), true);
        a.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (a.readyState == 4) if (a.status == 200) {
                b.raiseUploadComplete(Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize(a.responseText));
                b._processor.startUpload()
            }
            else {
                b.setFileStatus(c, "error", Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_error);
                b.raiseUploadError(a);
                throw "error raising upload complete event and start new upload";
            }
        };
        a.send(null);
    }
</script>
```

This code is the same function being used to call your page and trigger the UploadComplete event, only modified to add an extra parameter - uplCtrlID - which will contain the ID of the control that REALLY caused the event.

Set up your server side code as follows:

```
//set the OnUploadComplete property on all of your AjaxFileUpload controls to this method
protected void anyUploader_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        //call the correct upload complete handler if possible
        if (Request.QueryString["uplCtrlID"] != null)
        {
            //uplCtrlID (the query string param we injected with the overriden JS function)
            //contains the ID of the uploader.
            //We'll use that to fire the appropriate event handler...
            if (Request.QueryString["uplCtrlID"] == FileUploaderA.ClientID)
                FileUploaderA_UploadComplete(FileUploaderA, e);
            else if (Request.QueryString["uplCtrlID"] == FileUploaderB.ClientID)
                FileUploaderB_UploadComplete(FileUploaderB, e);
            //etc (or use a switch block - whatever suits you)
        }
    }
    protected void FileUploaderA_UploadComplete(AjaxFileUpload sender, AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        //logic here
    }
    protected void FileUploaderB_UploadComplete(AjaxFileUpload sender, AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        //logic here
    }
```

You're all set.  Multiple AjaxFileUpload controls on the same page, no problems.