# File name cannot be null error thrown ajaxfileupload (second control on my page)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, file-upload

I'm using ajaxFileUpload as described here: http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.aspx

I have to use three ajaxFileUpload controls on one page, to upload & save into different locations. 
At first, all uploader controls calling the UploadComplete event of first uploader (eg: ajaxFileupload2 always call ajaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete.)

Then I found the below post & try the last answer. 
[Ajax toolkit file upload is not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760895/ajax-toolkit-file-upload-is-not-called/16987292#16987292)

After I try with last answer, 3 uploaders are calling to their own event which is delegated by anyUploader event. However, facing another problem which is "Message: File name cannot be null" error thrown on second/third control, whereas first uploader is working fine.

```
Stack Trace:
Error found in FileUploadComplete2.
Message: File name cannot be null.
Parameter name: sourceFileName
Stack Trace:    at System.IO.File.Move(String sourceFileName, String destFileName)
   at AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUpload.SaveAs(String fileName, Boolean deleteAzureBlob) in f:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\80acd78aa4c25314\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\AjaxFileUpload\AjaxFileUpload.cs:line 473
   at AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUpload.SaveAs(String fileName) in f:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\80acd78aa4c25314\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\AjaxFileUpload\AjaxFileUpload.cs:line 441
   at FileUpload.AjaxFileUploadTwo_UploadComplete(Object sender, AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e) in c:\Projects\WebSite\FileUpload.aspx.cs:line 364
```

Appreciate any advice.

My main requirement is to allow user to simultaneous upload and save into different locations depending on which uploader they use.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the work around way to solve my problem. 
Since there is an error thrown with 'File name cannot be null' from second uploader onwards, below is my workaround way to solve & fulfil my project requirements.

1) I write one common function which is called by all three uploaders
 
2) Set the different path for each uploader which is define by ClientID (reference:[Ajax toolkit file upload is not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760895/ajax-toolkit-file-upload-is-not-called/16987292#16987292))
 
3) Use all the ajax function via AjaxUploadOne (Eg: AjaxUploadOne.SaveAs function for all three uploader). -- This line solved my problem. Before that, I'm using each uploader SaveAs function but it's not work as expected.

My sample code would be as follow & all ajaxfileupload controls called the same function:-

```
protected void AnyUploader_FileUploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string path = "";
            if (Request.QueryString["uplCtrlID"] != null)
            {
                //uplCtrlID (the query string param we injected with the overriden JS function)
                //contains the ID of the uploader.
                //We'll use that to fire the appropriate event handler...
                if (Request.QueryString["uplCtrlID"] == AjaxFileUploadOne.ClientID)
                {      
                    /** different path assignment for each uploader **/
                    path = @"C:\Temp\FileUploaderOne\";
                    if (!Directory.Exists(path))  Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                    AjaxFileUploadOne.SaveAs(path + e.FileName);                   
                }
                else if (Request.QueryString["uplCtrlID"] == AjaxFileUploadTwo.ClientID)
                {
      /** different path assignment for each uploader **/
                    path = @"C:\Temp\FileUploaderTwo\";
                    if (!Directory.Exists(path)) Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                    AjaxFileUploadOne.SaveAs(path + e.FileName);              
                }
                else if (Request.QueryString["uplCtrlID"] == AjaxFileUploadThree.ClientID)
                {
                    /** different path assignment for each uploader **/
                    path = @"C:\Temp\FileUploaderThree\";
                    if (!Directory.Exists(path)) Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                    AjaxFileUploadOne.SaveAs(path + e.FileName);                                    
                }
            }            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

I would be happy if it's help to someone who facing similar problem with me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upone this issue,
my solution involves a simple cast of the sender parameter;
in the event body I wrote :

```
 AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUpload FileUploadCurrentControl;
 FileUploadCurrentControl = (AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUpload)sender;
```

this for intercept the control holding the file.

After I wrote

```
FileUploadCurrentControl.SaveAs(FineName)
```

It worked for me.

Cheers.